# How to activate keybindings for GTKInspector?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, configuration, gtkinspector

I want to get involved with developing GNOME, and in [their newcomers guide it told me about GTKInspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK%2B/Inspector) and it says:

> To enable the debugger, either start your app with
>   GTK_DEBUG=interactive in your environment, or run gsettings set
>   org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding true and launch the
>   debugger with the Control-Shift-I or Control-Shift-D keyboard
>   shortcuts.

However upon running that code I just get the error:

```
No such schema 'org.gtk.Settings.Debug'
```

And the keyboard shortcuts don't work... So what do I do to activate them? And why is it not working? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 (from the `gnome3` and `gnome3-staging` PPAs). I have checked in the `dconf-editor` and there is definitely no `Debug` section in `org.gtk.Settings`...

Comment: Here on Arch Linux, I do have an `org.gtk.settings.debug` section (http://i.stack.imgur.com/p1k6J.png).

Comment: this feels like a bug and probably should be reported on launchpad

Comment: @fossfreedom: What's the bug though? That there is no `Debug` section or that the documentation is wrong? Or..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the schemas for that section are in the package `libgtk-3-dev` so make sure that that is installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```

And then if that is already installed, or installing that does not help you will need to manually load the schemas with:

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

This command should be run upon installing that package, so the fact that it did not is likely to be a bug with something in the `gnome3`/`gnome3-staging` PPA as the package in the standard repositories is fine and there is no problem with it.

And now that you have the `org.gtk.Settings.Debug` section you should now be able to run this command without error:

```
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding true
```

And the keyboard shortcuts should now work.